# ogr2ogr cannot import data

Tags: ogr, ogr2ogr, sql-server

I can successfully get a connection to my remote sql server database using:

```
ogrinfo "MSSQL:server=my_server_name;database=my_database;Trusted_Connection=True;"
```

But when I try to import an esri shape file (which works fine in QGIS) using the following command I found at various sites:

```
ogr2ogr -f "MSSQLSpatial" "MSSQL:server=my_server;database=my_database;Trusted_Connection=True" "NZ_RoadLink.shp" -a_srs "EPSG:27700"
```

I just get the following error. Given none of the examples say you have to create tables first I presumed it would do this, especially given there might be lots of columns to create. I have owner permissions.

I've also tried using '-nln mytable' and get teh same error of invalid object name 'dbo.mytable'

```
ERROR 1: INSERT command for new feature failed. [S0002][Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL 
Server]Invalid object name 'dbo.nz_roadlink'.(208)
ERROR 1: Unable to write feature 0 from layer NZ_RoadLink.
ERROR 1: Terminating translation prematurely after failed
translation of layer NZ_RoadLink (use -skipfailures to skip errors)
```

The full debug is:

```
GDAL: Auto register C:\OSGEO4~1\bin\gdalplugins\gdal_ECW_JP2ECW.dll using GDALRegister_ECW_JP2ECW.
GDAL: Auto register C:\OSGEO4~1\bin\gdalplugins\gdal_GEOR.dll using GDALRegister_GEOR.
GDAL: Auto register C:\OSGEO4~1\bin\gdalplugins\gdal_HDF5.dll using GDALRegister_HDF5.
GDAL: Auto register C:\OSGEO4~1\bin\gdalplugins\gdal_MG4Lidar.dll using GDALRegister_MG4Lidar.
GDAL: Auto register C:\OSGEO4~1\bin\gdalplugins\gdal_MrSID.dll using GDALRegister_MrSID.
GDAL: Auto register C:\OSGEO4~1\bin\gdalplugins\ogr_OCI.dll using RegisterOGROCI.
GDAL: Auto register C:\OSGEO4~1\bin\gdalplugins\ogr_SOSI.dll using RegisterOGRSOSI.
Shape: DBF Codepage = LDID/3 for NZ_RoadLink.shp
Shape: Treating as encoding 'CP1252'.
GDAL: GDALOpen(NZ_RoadLink.shp, this=000002464A4B8FE0) succeeds as ESRI Shapefile.
MSSQLSpatial: Use COPY/BCP: 0
ODBC: SQLDriverConnect(DRIVER={SQL Server};server=my_server;database=my_database;Trusted_Connection=True)
ODBC: SQLDisconnect()
GDAL: QuietDelete(MSSQL:server=my_server;database=my_database;Trusted_Connection=True) invoking Delete()
MSSQLSpatial: Use COPY/BCP: 0
ODBC: SQLDriverConnect(DRIVER={SQL Server};server=my_server;database=my_database;Trusted_Connection=True)
GDAL: GDALOpen(MSSQL:server=my_server;database=my_database;Trusted_Connection=True, this=000002464A4C2040) succeeds as MSSQLSpatial.
ODBC: SQLDisconnect()
GDAL: GDALClose(MSSQL:server=my_server;database=my_database;Trusted_Connection=True, this=000002464A4C2040)
GDAL: GDALDriver::Create(MSSQLSpatial,MSSQL:server=my_server;database=my_database;Trusted_Connection=True,0,0,0,Unknown,0000000000000000)
MSSQLSpatial: Use COPY/BCP: 0
ODBC: SQLDriverConnect(DRIVER={SQL Server};server=my_server;database=my_database;Trusted_Connection=True)
OGR_MSSQLSpatial: Using column ogr_fid as FID for table neilshape.
ERROR 1: INSERT command for new feature failed. [S0002][Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'dbo.neilshape'.(208)
ERROR 1: Unable to write feature 0 from layer NZ_RoadLink.
ERROR 1: Terminating translation prematurely after failed
translation of layer NZ_RoadLink (use -skipfailures to skip errors)
ODBC: SQLDisconnect()
GDAL: GDALClose(MSSQL:server=my_server;database=my_database;Trusted_Connection=True, this=000002464A4C2040)
Shape: 1 features read on layer 'NZ_RoadLink'.
GDAL: GDALClose(NZ_RoadLink.shp, this=000002464A4B8FE0)
GDAL: In GDALDestroy - unloading GDAL shared library.
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by adding:

```
-lco UPLOAD_GEOM_FORMAT=wkt
```

So the invalid object name error is complete nonsense.

However, after 40 minutes of a small 30mb shape file that is read in about 5 seconds in QGIS it was still on 1% progress because it refuses to use BCP or the native sql drivers that every other app uses.

Comment: If you want to debug you should capture the SQL commands that GDAL executes. Probably you must do that from the MSSQL side.

Comment: I found the problems using debug, thanks. I dunno why it needed wkt adding as other colleagues don't need it on same file. Also, it refuses to use any driver I specify despite every other app using native or odbc drivers fine, and so BCP is disabled. I had to give up in the end and use somebody elses computer with the same command..

Answer (score 0):

For me `'-nln mytable'` switch is a perfectly valid object name `'dbo.mytable'`

Upgrading to the latest version of ogr2ogr fixed it.